# Monero wallet GUI, unable to execute on KDE Raspbian OS (RPi Model 4B+)

Tags: raspberry-pi

Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
-bash: /usr/bin/monero-wallet-gui: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

Answer (score 1):

There isn't currently a release build of the GUI wallet for ARM (which is the architecture of Raspberry Pi's). So if you want to run the GUI wallet on an RPi, you need to build it yourself from source.

Comment: Ah Ok I see now this is the reason behind it... Yeah It is kinda sucks I have to build everything from the source only itself... when you cannot or unable to download the monero GUI on your windows laptop lol bcz of my antivirus software...